# In planetside 2, what support activities give experience?

Tags: planetside-2

In particular:-

- does a sunderer/S-AMS pilot get XP for providing a spawn point?
- does an engineer get XP for resupplying ammo?
- under what circumstances does a combat medic (or engineer) gain xp for healing (or repairing)?

Comment: Related:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95423/2578

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> does a sunderer/S-AMS pilot get XP for providing a spawn point?

A deployed Sunderer will give the pilot 5 XP each time a player uses it as a spawn point.

> does an engineer get XP for resupplying ammo?

For each tick of ammo resupplied to a unit, the engineer gains 10 XP.

> under what circumstances does a combat medic (or engineer) gain xp for healing (or repairing)?

For every x seconds of continuous healing (or y hit points healed continuously, not sure) 10 XP is awarded to the medic.  The same goes for repairs but with a reward of 5 XP.  Reviving a player rewards 75 XP. Healing/repairing damage that was inflicted by an ally provides no XP.

In each of the above cases, the XP reward is increased when interacting with a player in your squad.

Comment: Note that the exact figures for XP earned are subject to change over time as Sony changes and patches the game, and most of these figures are likely to be out of date.  There are also some big patches coming up which will (IIRC) buff the XP earned for support activities.

Comment: Yep, and they have changed quite a bit.