# PlanetSide 2 Cert Points System

Tags: planetside-2

How do Certification points work in PlanetSide 2?

Do you get some:

- over time?
- by getting kills?
- by completing objectives?

If so, how many do you get for each of the above?

Comment: AFAIK you get one cert point every 250 xp, then refer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89798/1721) to see what gives the most xp

Comment: You also earn Certs while being offline, so you do not fall too far behind the curve if you do not play for a while, explained [here](http://forums.station.sony.com/ps2/index.php?threads/certification-gains-while-offline.57183/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You gain 1 Certification Point every 250 XP.

XP is gained by

- Killing enemies
- Capturing bases
- Repairing vehicles, MAX units or turrets,
- Healing or reviving allies,
- Hacking terminals (Infiltrator),
- Resupplying allies (Engineer or Sunderer with Ammo Dispenser)

You also get 12 Certification Points per day by just logging in.

If you want to gain experience (and thus Certification Points) at a faster rate you can buy a membership or one of the short term [experience boosts](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Boosts) (or both at once, even better) with Station Cash (bought with real money).

Answer (score 1):

Also, getting badges for your weapons gets certs. (Although it's technically still kills.) For almost every weapon in the game, when you get 10 kills you get bronze medal and 2 certs, 50 kills gives you a silver medal and 10 certs, 100 kills gives you a gold medal and 20 certs, and finally 1000 kills gives you a purple medal and 200 certs. It maxes out at purple, and if you are saving up for weapons can be useful to switch to another after it maxes.

Answer (score 0):

There are also these that can get you XP (especially a well placed sundy):

- Spot enemies (by default - Q key while pointing at enemy)
- Spawning - either by deploying a sunderer, or a beacon as a squad leader
- Driving a vehicle which has turrets that can be populated, and get XP from enemies killed by these turrets